# Changing the layout of a custom options page

Tags: theme-options, options

I've followed the guide [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) to create a custom options page for my theme using `add_options_page`. By default, these are arranged as a list:

[image: Default layout]

Ideally, I'd want these options arranged in a grid with rows of five. How do I override the default WordPress options styling to accomplish this?

This is the code I'm using, based on Example #2 in the link above:

```
class MySettingsPage
{
    /**
     * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Start up
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'featured_content_menu' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'custom_page_init' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Add options page
     */
    public function featured_content_menu()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Featured Content', 
            'Featured Content', 
            'manage_options', 
            'set-featured-content', 
            array( $this, 'create_featured_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Options page callback
     */
    public function create_featured_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'featured_content' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php screen_icon(); ?>
            <h2>Set Featured Content</h2>           
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( 'set_featured_genres' );   
                do_settings_sections( 'set-featured-content' );
                submit_button(); 
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }




    /**
     * Register and add settings
     */
    public function custom_page_init()
    {        
        register_setting(
            'set_featured_genres', // Option group
            'featured_content', // Option name
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'featured_genre_id', // ID
            'Featured Genres', // Title
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
            'set-featured-content' // Page
        );  

        add_settings_field(
            'featured_genre_1', // ID
            'Genre 1', // Title 
            array( $this, 'featured_genre_1_callback' ), // Callback
            'set-featured-content', // Page
            'featured_genre_id' // Section           
        );      

    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        $new_input = array();
        if( isset( $input['featured_genre_1'] ) )
            $new_input['featured_genre_1'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['featured_genre_1'] );    

        return $new_input;
    }

    /** 
     * Print the Section text
     */
    public function print_section_info()
    {
        print 'Select featured genres below:';
    }

    /** 
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function featured_genre_1_callback()
    {

      echo '<select id="featured_genre_1" name="featured_content[featured_genre_1]" >';

      $categories = get_terms( 'genre', array(
          'orderby'    => 'count',
          'hide_empty' => 0
      ) );
      $output = 'objects'; // or names
      if  ($categories) {
        foreach ($categories  as $category ) {
          $selected = ($category->name == $this->options['featured_genre_1']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
          echo '<option value="' . $category->name . '" '.$selected.' >' . $category->name . '</option>';
        }
      } 
      echo '</select>';

    }


}
```

Comment: Its simple and easy to code. - http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/10/creating-custom-options-page-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to edit the appropriate stylesheet so that the divs using the class "wrap" float to the left of each other. If "wrap" is being used elsewhere by Wordpress I would give this a new name such as "mywrap." You might also want to give that a width of 20% with 0 padding and 0 margins to make sure they all fit. You might need to experiment a bit to get it to fit.

Comment: The fields are displayed in a table, so that won't work.